# Mapping an integer to array (Python): ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a defaultdict which maps certain integers to a numpy array of size 20.

In addition, I have an existing array of indices. I want to turn that array of indices into a 2D array, where each original index is converted into an array via my defaultdict.

Finally, in the case that an index isn't found in the defaultdict, I want to create an array of zeros for that index.

Here's what I have so far

```
    converter = lambda x: np.zeros((d), dtype='float32') if x == -1 else cVf[x]
    vfunc = np.vectorize(converter)
    cvf = vfunc(indices)
```

`np.zeros((d), dtype='float32')` and `cVf[x]` are identical data types/ shapes:

```
(Pdb) np.shape(cVf[0])
(20,)
```

Yet I get the error in the title (*** ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.) when I try to run this code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give us a some sample arrays or dictionaries (in the case of `cVF`, so we can make a test run.

Read what `vectorize` has to say about the return value. Since you don't define `otypes`, it makes a test calculation to determine the dtype of the returned array.  My first thought was that the test calc and subsequent one might be returning different things.  But you claim `converter` will always be returning the same dtype and shape array.

But let's try something simpler:

```
In [609]: fv = np.vectorize(lambda x: np.array([x,x]))
In [610]: fv([1,2,3])
...
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

It's having trouble with returning any array.

But if I give an `otypes`, it works

```
In [611]: fv = np.vectorize(lambda x: np.array([x,x]), otypes=[object])
In [612]: fv([1,2,3])
Out[612]: array([array([1, 1]), array([2, 2]), array([3, 3])], dtype=object)
```

In fact in this case I could use `frompyfunc`, which returns object dtype, and is the underlying function for `vectorize` (and a bit faster).

```
In [613]: fv = np.frompyfunc(lambda x: np.array([x,x]), 1,1)
In [614]: fv([1,2,3])
Out[614]: array([array([1, 1]), array([2, 2]), array([3, 3])], dtype=object)
```

`vectorize` and `frompyfunc` are designed for functions that are `scalar in- scalar out`.  That scalar may be an object, even array, but is still treated as a scalar.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I particularly appreciate your in depth response despite my post lacking sample variables. Thanks!